# template expression looping with split on a string input

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

```
  - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.buildDockerImages, true), eq(parameters.buildSingleServiceDockerImages, true)) }}:
      - stage: publish_docker_images
        dependsOn: publish_service_names
        variables:
          services: $($[stageDependencies.publish_service_names.get_services.outputs['getservices.serviceName']])
        jobs:
          - ${{ each service in variables.services.split(',') }}:
            - template: ./build-push-single-docker.yaml
              parameters:
                acrServiceConnection: ${{ parameters.acrServiceConnection}}
                serviceName: "${{ service }}"
                friendlyName: "${{service }}"
                repositoryPathPrefix: ${{ parameters.repositoryPathPrefix }}
                fixedTag: ${{ parameters.fixedTag }}
```

build-push-single-docker.yaml

```
jobs:
  - job: publish_${{ parameters.serviceName }}
    pool:
      ${{ if eq(parameters.useCustomAgentPool, true) }}:
        name: ${{ parameters.customAgentPoolName }}
      ${{ if eq(parameters.useCustomAgentPool, false) }}:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - bash: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildArtifact;]ailens_services_supplemented_with_client_package"
        condition: eq('${{ parameters.addClientToSingleboxAndGUI }}', true)
        displayName: "Set artifact name"
```

my service list is of type service1,service2. The build-push-single-docker is triggered for complete string service1,service2 . split is not working for template loop expressions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way it's going to work. `${{ }}` is a compile-time expression, but `variables['services']` is a run-time expression. At a moment of evaluating this `- ${{ each service in split(variables['services'], ',')}}:`, `variables['services']` is empty.

Comment: Any solution to run the build-push-single-docker in loop for all service names?